# Checking if a boolean column is true in MySQL/Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

Rails and MySQL:

I have a table with several boolean columns representing tags. I want to find all the rows for which a specific one of these columns is 'true' (or I guess in the case of MySQL, '1'). I have the following code in my view.

```
@tag = params[:tag]

@supplies = Supply.find(:all,
  :conditions=>["? IS NOT NULL and ? !=''", @tag, @tag], :order=>'name')
```

The @tag is being passed in from the url. Why is it then that I am instead getting all of my @supplies (i.e. every row) rather than just those that are true for the column for @tag.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `params[:tag]` is set to `foo`, the `find` method is generating this query:

```
select * from supplies where 'foo' is not null and 'foo' != '' order by name;
```

This is returning all your `Supply` records because both conditions are always true.

1. `'foo' is not null`
2. `'foo' != ''`

Of course you're intending for `params[:tag]` to be a column name, but that is just terrible design.

You should have a `tag` attribute on your `Supply` model and use the following finder:

```
@supplies = Supply.all(:conditions => ["tag = ?", params[:tag]], :order => "name")
```

---

If you really want the ability for Supplies to have the option for multiple Tags, use:

```
class Supply < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags
end

class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :supplies
end

@supplies = Supplies.all(:conditions => {:tags => ['foo', 'bar']}, :order => "name")
```

Comment: I do have a tag attribute currently. What is the best way to assign multiple values to that attribute so that I can use the finder you mentioned in the last line?

Comment: Pygmalion, you can't have multiple values for one attribute. A `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship uses a `join table` (often times called a `mapping table`, too). To learn more about `has_and_belongs_to_many`, see the api: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#M001836

Answer (score -1):

I think this is what you want to do

```
@tag = params[:tag]
@supplies = Supply.find(:all, :conditions=>["? = ?", @tag, true], :order=>'name')
```